# Identify development vs. production server in PHP

Tags: php

I work with two application servers on a daily basis: one development, one production. A variety of apps from different developers live on these boxes, as well as some scripts that run via cron. Currently, I am using the [`-D` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html) to httpd so that I can identify my production server in code, ie. `isset($_SERVER['DEV'])`. Unfortunately, this does not work for scripts run from the command line since they're not under the Apache umbrella.

Essentially, **I would like a clean, simple way to identify development vs. production that is available to every line of code**.

What I have ruled out:

- `auto_prepend_file` -- we are already using this directive in some applications, and you can't have more than one autoprepend.

What I am currently exploring:

- Custom extension -- I'm sure creating a new extension that only defines a new constant (possibly influenced by an ini setting) would not be the hardest thing in the world, but I have no prior experience in this area.

So, got any tricks for identifying dev/prod that doesn't involve injecting code into every script or application?

Answer (score 23):

### use an environment variable

Just set an environment variable. It works on Windows and linux, they are even called the same thing now. Then just check `$_ENV["DEVVSPROD"]`

Comment: Not bad. I would have to get our sysadmins to drop `export DEV=1` into the global bash/tsch rc files, and there is the potential that it would get clobbered by `env -i`. I wonder what sort of environment cron'd scripts get.

Comment: Actually, the crontab entries themselves can contain environment variable assignments, plus the normal shell rules will apply when cron starts a shell to run the process. See also `pam_env(8)`. Heh, I believe `grub(8)` can pass environment variables to the kernel.

Comment: I love it. Very simple to add an environment variable to everyone's system, and impossible for a user to spoof. This feels like the most secure and reliable answer I've yet to find - until you forget to set the variable when you reload a system, lol. If you are doing command line, make sure to use `getenv()` since superglobals aren't normally available. `define('DEV', getenv('DEV'));` works beautifully - the function returns `false` if the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: realize that if you (or a new team member) forgets to set the variable or the variable is missing due to a startup script failing, your app is now using live data. thats probably not what you want.

Answer (score 9):

I usually just do something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost') // or any other host
{
     // development
}

else
{
     // production
}
```

Comment: `define('IN_PRODUCTION', ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'localhost'));`

Comment: I know this is old, but I would like to point out that this isn't 100% accurate. If you have your production server setup to catch all host names (which is usually common), someone could craft the HTTP Host header to be localhost and possibly get debug information that they shouldn't see.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using `$_ENV['HOSTNAME']`, with `php_uname("n")` as a backup:

```
/**  
 * Returns true if we are working on a development server, determined by server's
 * hostname. Will generate an error if run on an unknown host.
 */
public static function isdev()
{
  static $isdev = null;

  // don't run function body more than once
  if( null !== $isdev ) {
    return $isdev;
  }    

  // prefer HOSTNAME in the environment, which will be set in Apache.
  // use `uname -n' as a backup.
  if( isset( $_ENV['HOSTNAME'] ) ) {
    $hostname = $_ENV['HOSTNAME'];
  } else {
    $hostname = php_uname("n");
  }    

  switch( $hostname ) {
    case 'production1.example.com':
    case 'production2.example.com':
    case 'production3.example.com': $isdev = false; break;

    case 'dev1.example.com':
    case 'dev2':
    case 'dev2.example.com': $isdev = true; break;

    default: trigger_error( 'HOSTNAME is set to an unknown value', E_USER_ERROR );
  }    

  return $isdev;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This came to my mind

```
if(filter_var(ini_get('display_errors'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN))
{
    // development
} 
else {
    // production
}
```

or a better approach

```
define('IN_DEVELOPEMENT', filter_var(ini_get('display_errors'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
```

Answer (score 1):

A company I worked for previously used a convention of suffixing servers as follows:

- L = Live
- D = Dev
- T = Test
- U = UAT

This makes determining the environment that you're working on, both inside and outside of Apache, fairly trivial.

Comment: Good stuff. UAT = User Acceptance Testing?

Comment: One major caveat of this approach is that this implies that the company owns i.e. controls _all_ servers. For instance, if you use 3rd party for production, I'd doubt they would allow you to specify your own host names