# Global vs. Define

Tags: php

I have a php file in which I need to be able to easily flip a switch.  The switch is set to 1 for local server and 0 for production server.  local_on='1'; or local_on='0';.  Which way is better (creating a global or using define)? If either way is good which way is best practice?

Comment: I was just about to answer `define` when 3 people who type faster did so before me.  Do what they said.

Comment: it's more semantic to use true/false instead of '1'/'0'

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412557/identify-development-vs-production-server-in-php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`define`. You can't change its value later, and its value is always available in all scopes, tersely.

Answer (score 12):

A global variable is, as its name indicates, **variable** -- which means its value can be changed by any portion of your code ; which, in your case, is probably not what you want.

On the other hand, a constant *(that you'll set with `define`)* is... well... **constant** ; and, as such, cannot be modified once set ; which is probably what you want, in your case.

Considering the variable vs constant idea, for this kind of switches, I generally use `define()` and constants.

Comment: Define symbols and constants are really different things.

Answer (score 4):

The define is the better choice of the two, because global variables are bad news for reasons I'm sure you're already familiar with, and because you have to remember to declare `global $var` in every function and method in your code. Defined constants are automatically available everywhere. Additionally, a variable could inadvertently be set from one state to the other during the running of your script. This could cause some really hard-to-find bugs if it happened.

Comment: "because you have to remember to declare `global $var` in every function and method in your code" // No, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `define`. Reasons:

- You can't redefine it accidentally
- You can use in other scope (ex. functions) without ugly $GLOBALS construction

PS: since PHP 5.3 you can use `const` , not only `define` to declare constants. It's more readable for me

Answer (score 2):

Another way that performs a little better than define symbols and minimizes name clashes is a class declaration like

```
abstract config {
    const LOCAL = true; // toggle to false
// or maybe
    const SERVER = 'local'; // toggle to 'remote'
// (maybe having if (config.SERVER == 'remote') would be more readable in some
// cases than if (!config.LOCAL) depends on your app)
}
```

Comment: the ! part is a matter of taste depending on the context.  The use of a class const instead of a define is categorically better for code and efficiency reasons.

Comment: const valuename = 'smth' is available out of class since 5.3 too. I think efficiency reasons are not actuall here. Anyway I agree that class make code more accuracy  if there are more than 1 constant

Answer (score 1):

Both work fine as long as you remember to choose a distinctive name (all-uppercase for `define`s) and use the modern way to access global variables via the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) superglobal (sic). Also, global variables are, well, *variable*, so you could, in theory, change its value by accident or so.

To simplify deployment and not setting or unsetting the switch by accident, I'd recommend automatically setting it automatically by examining the properties of [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), like

```
// Turn on debugging code on local machine
define('MYPAGE_LOCAL_ON', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'my-dev-box');
```

Also, I don't see why you'd set the switch to a string or an integer for that matter. The [boolean values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) `true` and `false` seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In short terms, `define` is what you look for ([for said reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975083/global-vs-define/6975105#6975105)).

However, come the future development, you might look for something like a dependency for your whole application providing the context it is running in. This can not be done with constants, so then `define` but as well as *global variables* are both wrong.