# Reliable way to tell development server apart from production server?

Tags: language-agnostic, configuration, production

Here are the ways I've come up with:

1. Have an unversion-controlled config file
2. Check the server-name/IP address against a list of known dev servers
3. Set some environment variable that can be read

I've used (2) on some of my projects, and that has worked well with only one dev machine, but we're up to about 10 now, it may become difficult to manage an ever-changing list.

(1) I don't like, because that's an important file and it *should* be version controlled.

(3) I've never tried. It requires more configuration when we set up each server, but it could be an OK solution.

Are there any others I've missed? What are the pros/cons?

Comment: Tell them apart in what context? Naming all our production servers with the suffix `PROD` seems to work.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412557/identify-development-vs-production-server-in-php

Comment: @Widor: The context? I need to know what server the code is running on so that I can connect to a different database or turn debugging on or off.

Comment: @CarlWinder: I had not. That's pretty much exactly what I want. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

(3) doesn't have to require more configuration on the servers. You could instead default to server mode, and require more configuration on the dev machines.

In general I'd always want to make the dev machines the special case, and release behavior the default. The only tricky part is that if the relevant setting is in the config file, then developers will keep accidentally checking in their modified version of the file. You can avoid this either in your version-control system (for example a checkin hook), or:

- read two config files, one of which is allowed to not exist (and only exists on dev machines, or perhaps on servers set up by expert users)
- read an environment variable that is allowed to not exist.

Personally I prefer to have a config override file, just because you've already got the code to load the one config file, it should be pretty straightforward to add another. Reading the environment isn't exactly difficult, of course, it's just a separate mechanism.

Some people really like their programs to be controlled by the environment (especially those who want to control them when running from scripts. They don't want to have to write a config file on the fly when it's so easy to set the environment from a script). So it might be worth using the environment from that POV, but not just for this setting.

Another completely different option: make dev/release mode configurable within the app, if you're logged into the app with suitable admin privileges. Whether this is a good idea might depend whether you have the kind of devs who write debug logging messages along the lines of, "I can't be bothered to fix this, but no customer is ever going to tell the difference, they're all too stupid." If so, (a) don't allow app admins to enable debug mode (b) re-educate your devs.

Comment: The thing about the config files is if you do this exist/not-exists shannanigans, it doesn't work very well. Like I said in the Q, it would have to be not version controlled so that it doesn't accidentally make it to production, but I *do* want it in version control because they should be shared among the devs. I think an environment variable would work better here, and then I could use that to determine which config file to load. And as you said, it doesn't have to exist on production.

Comment: @Mark: if you prefer. I don't see how you're going to use version control to share the environment variable. And if you don't need to share that via version-control, I don't really see why you need to share the one-line config file via version control. Anyway, as I already said there might be ways to share the config file via version control read-only, so the devs check it out, change "dev = false" to "dev = true", and then version-control magic ensures that change either can't be committed, or else can't be released (details vary by system).

Comment: Basically: with the environment variable you have to instruct all your devs to run `export DEV=true`. With the supplementary config file you have to instruct all your devs to run `echo "DEV=true" >> config-override.txt`. I don't see why one of those would work very well and the other one wouldn't. The real criteria on which to choose which to use are what I said about whether the environment or a config file is a more convenient way to control the app in general, for all configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few other possibilities.

Some organizations keep development machines on one network, and production machines on another network, for example, `dev.example.com` and `prod.example.com`. If your organization uses that practice, then an application can determine its environment via the fully-qualified hostname on which it is running, or perhaps by examining some bits in its IP address.

Another possibility is to use an embeddable scripting language (Tcl, Lua and Python come to mind) as the syntax of your configuration file. Doing that means your configuration file can easily query environment variables (or IP addresses) and use that to drive an `if-then-else` statement. A drawback of this approach is the potential security risk of somebody editing a configuration file to add malicious code (for example, to delete files).

A final possibility is to start each application via a shell/Python/Perl script. The script can query its environment and then use that to driven an `if-then-else` statement for passing a command-line option to the "real" application.

By the way, I don't like to code an environment-testing `if-then-else` statement as follows:

```
if (check-for-running-in-production) {
    ... // run program in production mode
} else {
    ... // run program in development mode
}
```

The above logic silently breaks if the `check-for-running-in-production` test has not been updated to deal with a newly added production machine. Instead, if prefer to code a bit more defensively:

```
if (check-for-running-in-production) {
    ... // run program in production mode
} else if (check-for-running-in-development) {
    ... // run program in development mode
} else {
    print "Error: unknown environment"
    exit
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. We presently use the URL scheme but it's recently caused problems because we changed our URL structure; I wanted to avoid having that problem again in the future. I don't see the security risk of using a programming language for the config file; if they can get into that file, they can get into the rest of our code, and we have a much bigger issue at hand. Lastly, I would simple check if it was running in dev, and if not, default to production. If a dev server accidentally runs in production mode because it isn't set up right, it's no biggie. If a production server errors --

Comment: -- out because it isn't set up properly (or reveals debug info), that's a bigger issue.